# After updating to iOS 6, iPhone will not charge from Mac Pro USB ports

Tags: iphone, usb, ios

Immediately before I downloaded and updated to iOS 6, my phone charged in my computer's tower front USB port. Immediately following, it will not. I plugged it into my wall charger at home and it charges fine. Has anyone run into this and/or solved it yet?

Comment: Not seeing anything like this with my iPhone 4 after updating to iOS6.  Have you restarted both the Mac Pro and the iPhone?

Comment: That was it. I had restarted my phone and thought that I had restarted my Mac. Thanks for the suggestion/reminder Stu. Sheesh, it's like that SNL skit…

Comment: Even though this seems trivial - please accept the answer that is right or add your own answer. You were not the first to have this problem and you won't be the last.

Comment: The 1.8.2 update acted strangely, and took an additional reboot before returning to normal

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather peculiar problem, and I have not found any more widespread reports of this problem.

Try rebooting everything; that often helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing anything like this with my iPhone 4 after updating to iOS6.

So I'd expect the usual suspects; try restarting both the Mac Pro and the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the asker hadn't restarted her Mac, and the problem was not something that lasted after the reboot so the charging either fixed itself and the reboot was as good as her going to make some tea to drink (let time pass) or the reboot was needed fix the issue.

So, if this happens to you, reboot and make a pot of tea. If that doesn't fix it, you can always ask another question here with your details and we'll see what we can do to help.